# Handle Node Js schedule

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, mongoose, node-schedule

I need some help. Here, you can see I created a Mongoose model and statics. In this system, a user can create tasks and assign them to employees. Additionally, the user can configure the date and time. The main factor is implementing a reminder system. Users can configure daily, weekly, or monthly reminders. If a user creates a task for 8 a.m. and repeats it daily, I need to handle cron jobs at 8 a.m. every day. Users can configure any time from 8 a.m. to 11:59 p.m.

For this scenario, handling cron jobs every minute is necessary because I don't know which user created tasks for specific times, like 8:10 a.m. and another at 8:11 a.m. However, creating cron jobs for every minute may overload the server due to frequent API calls. What is a good way to handle this efficiently? How do developers manage this type of system effectively?

I use Node.js, Express.js, and Mongoose. For cron jobs, I use the node-scheduler package.

Thank you.
The code:[image]

Comment: How big is the system? In case of smaller systems and properly designed databases scheduling the job every minute shouldn't have a significant impact on the server. In `node-cron` you can even schedule your tasks every second. You can also think about some DB caching like Redis or aggregating the tasks (e.g. you run the cronjob every 5 minutes and run all the tasks that should've been executed during that period).

Comment: @DanielStasiak Not too much big. like in a time it is used by highest 2-5k  users. I dont understand what are you told in last 2 lines. Could you explain it

Comment: Your schema contains the `time` field. Depending on the case you may want to do the tasks aggregation: run the cronjob not every minute but less often, let's say every 5 minutes (it can be anything: 2, 3, 10 minutes etc.). Then during the cronjob execution you can get the tasks that have been scheduled for the last 5 minutes (e.g. between 4:05 PM and 4:10 PM) and then execute them. With this approach you may also limit the UI to input only times like 12:00, 12:05, 12:10 etc. (e.g. iPhone reminders are limited like this). Of course it depends on how accurate you want the tasks time to be.

Comment: @DanielStasiak thank you. so do you suggest it is not a big issue in that case?? right?

Comment: I believe it's not but the best thing would be to do some monitoring tests and check whether the machine resources are fine (it's still possible they are exhausted if the database contains many records and retrieving the tasks take much time). Make some exaggerated estimation as well (e.g. assume there are more users and tasks than there actually are, so it's not the problem in the future).